# Accessing machine by name in a Windows 2003 RRAS VPN not working as required

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, rras, wins

I have a Windows 2003 RRAS VPN with two clients (both running Windows 7).  The VPN works as expected, except that I am unable to access any of the three machines in the network using their Windows names.

The server has a static IP, and the clients are assigned IPs dynamically in a specified address range.  However, every time a client disconnects and reconnects it is likely to be assigned a different IP.

I have put the server's IP in my hosts file which permits me to reach the machine in Windows Explorer using `\\MachineName`.  `\\192.168.150.XXX` works to access the other machines, but as noted this changes.

What do I need to do to get `\\MachineName` to work dynamically as the IPs change?  Is this a WINS issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a DNS issue. You need to make sure that your VPN clients use your internal DNS server when they're connected via VPN.

Comment: Thanks @Joel.  I have tried putting pointing clients to the DNS server to which the Windows 2003 box points, this didn't work.

Comment: Can you do an nslookup from a VPN client against that DNS server? Example nslookup google.com IP.of.internal.DNS

Answer (score 0):

To enable name based communication in a private subnet without the use of DNS, you'll need to enable NetBios over TCP/IP. This enables the machines to query NetBIOS name (the machine names) through broadcasting name queries and thus discovering client addresses by name.

To enable NetBT, go to Advanced TCP/IP Settings for the interface you want to enable NetBT for, and select the WINS tab, as explained [here(Win2003)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727013.aspx) and [here(Win7)](http://ttcshelbyville.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/enable-netbios-over-tcpip/)

Comment: this was a new idea for me, thank you.  I turned on NetBios on the server (was already turned on for clients).  Unfortunately no name resolution.  Opened up ports 139 on all machines.  No luck.

Comment: Do you use Windows DHCP?

Comment: No DHCP server on the box.  VPN IPs assigned, I believe, by RRAS.